# UIView does not resize when orientation changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am making a custom UIView using the following function. It renders fine in whichever orientation you start with but once rendered, if I change the orientation it does not resize properly. Am I doing something wrong in the function?

```
class func getRoundedView(text: String, view: UIView, color: UIColor, textColor: UIColor) -> UIView {

        var returnView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height))

        var innerViewX : CGFloat = 0.1 * (returnView.frame.size.width)
        var innerViewY : CGFloat = 0.1 * (returnView.frame.size.height)
        var innerViewWidth : CGFloat = 0.8 * (returnView.frame.size.width)
        var innerViewHeight : CGFloat = 0.8 * (returnView.frame.size.height)
        var innerView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(innerViewX, innerViewY, innerViewWidth, innerViewHeight))
        innerView.backgroundColor = color

        var corner : UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner.AllCorners
        var maskPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corner, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0))
        var maskLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = innerView.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
        innerView.layer.mask = maskLayer

        var label : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, innerView.frame.size.width, innerView.frame.size.height))
        label.text = text
        label.center = CGPointMake(innerView.frame.size.width / 2.0, innerView.frame.size.height / 2.0)
        label.textColor = textColor
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin

        innerView.addSubview(label)
        innerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin

        returnView.addSubview(innerView)
        returnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        returnView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin

        return returnView

    }
```

Comment: Is the function being rerun when you change orientations?

Comment: Also in landscape mode you have to swap the height and width around.

Comment: No the function is being run on when the orientation is changed. I thought that `autoresizingMask` takes care of that. Hmm, so basically I have to remove the view when orientation changes and generate it again? Is there a better way?

Comment: You could use constraints?